# Change folder icon in asp tree view control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" 
    runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("LibName") %>' 
    CommandName="Update"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LibID") %>' 
    Visible='<%# Eval("FolderVisibility") %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I have an  asp. net folder tree and my users would like to change the folders to a grey color if they have been marked not visible. I found an icon and have added to my project. I was trying to figure out the best way to effect this change. Should i use a javascript function? I am having trouble locating where the image file path gets set. So any help would be appreciated. I had something like this in mind to begin with.

```
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById("#lnk").style.visibility
};
```

[image: foldertree]

Comment: Where did you place your image on the server - Images folder? Where is the image in your linkbutton - in the code you have provided it's not available.

Comment: image is in image folder. along with original image for yellow folder icon. I cant figure out where the path is set.

Comment: Can you please tell where you putting your image on the page? it is not shown in the code above

Comment: The image is going on the folder tree. It replaces the yellow folders with a grey one in case the folder visibility has been set to hidden.

Comment: Can you please post the code with actual <img src='...' /> tag.

Comment: There is not img src tag because the asp tree control generates the tree dynamically based on server info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I would use CSS to do that.  I would add a class element on the ASP

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LibName") %>' CommandName="Update"
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LibID") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("FolderVisibility") %>'  Class='Visible<%# Eval("FolderVisibility") %>'></asp:LinkButton>


So in the HTML the class will come out like "Class='VisibleTrue'" or "Class='VisibleFlase'" 

in the CSS you can create a two classes

>     .VisibleFlase{
//Icon css here
},
.VisibleTrue{
//icon Css here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should try

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/yourgreyimg.jpg")"
    alt="GrayFolder" />
```